# Bypass Internet in mobile

Tags: internet, android-versions, vpn, proxy, openvpn

ur college provides wifi,but it cannot be used by mobile devices.. Wifi is connected.. Only app notification are received.. Whatsapp works(images/videos can't be downloaded.. Only text ) have tried many vpn and proxy apps.. Lately tried using psiphon.. For pc authorities have provided us with proxy: port to access Internet..tried those on mobile as well.. Doesn't work. Any solution to use the campus wifi?

Comment: I am not sure, but try using apps like tunnelBear (VPN or tunneling) app. You can browse internet as you are using it from outside your country.

Comment: Sorry that comment wasn't intended to you.. But thanks.. I have tried all vpn apps..But all in vain

Comment: Depends on how is the "protection" implemented. Unless we know that, we can only speculate here. More thorough testing is required and this testing would most likely be if not illegal, at least very shady.

Comment: @mikky you got any ideas on how I could it?

Comment: I've got many. But I'm not sure which one *you* could use since I have no idea what is your networking proficiency. What is your computer networking experience?

Comment: I'm doing IT Engineering in the college of which I'm talking abt.. We are allowed net access in out lab.. And we are provided proxy: port for it i.e 10.10.0.23:8089 using this we can access Internet.. Further many sites are also blocked.. But we have listed out certain lesser know proxy sites for that purpose.. But I need to know how could we use that Internet in mobile, on using the provided proxy : port only play store is accessible and app notification are received(football scores,whatsapp(only text) ).Tried various vpn apps.. Those were even unable to connect to server.  Any solution now?